# Change Highstocks.js Y axis value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm not quite sure how Highstocks is drawing my graphic. The starting point for the Y-axis is always 0 for any series when their values are always over that value.

In some cases the values are negative in the Y-axis and sometimes multiple series overlap each other when they have very different values between them.

I'm probably misunderstanding how it's working but I can not find more information about it.
Any help will be appreciated.

---

[image]

---

The highest value is under the lowest one?

[image]

```
$.getJSON(baseUrl + "monitor/data", function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var seriesOptions = [];

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        console.log(item);

        seriesOptions.push({
            name: i,
            data: item,
        });
    });



    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'stats'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'value',
                pointInterval: 1000 * 30
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y} K</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            yDecimals: 1,
            shared: true
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });

});
```

Comment: You need to show your chart object configuration, otherwise we can only guess what is wrong. Maybe you have set `compare` option, while you don't want to?

Comment: I set it to `value`. Updated answer.

Comment: Fine, I realized I just have to delete the `compare` option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to remove 'compare' option.

[Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.compare).